# .NET version of Java's assertGC: Unit tesing memory leaks

Tags: .net, unit-testing, memory-leaks, .net-4.0, garbage-collection

I am trying to write a unit test using .NET 4 to ensure that an object can be garbage collected after some code is run. In Java, I would use assertGC to ensure that a weak reference is collected. How can I write this type of test for .NET?

I have tried keeping a `WeakReference` to the object and calling `GC.Collect()`, but as you'd expect, sometimes my object is collected and sometimes it is not. Note that this is for a unit test, not production code. I would not want GC.Collect() in my real code base.

I'm using C# but the same answer will be good for VB.NET too.

Comment: Why are you unit testing this, it sounds like you are writing a unit test for the .net framework's memory management. What are you actually testing for?

Comment: @Ben Robinson, I am unit testing that I am not accidentally referencing my object from a static variable (e.g. a cache) and that the object can be garbage collected. The system I am working on has a large code base and lots of configurable modules that might cause my object to be referenced by code other people write.

Comment: [Raymond Chen](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/) currently has his CLR week and his topics this week sound suspiciously similar to your problem.

Comment: @Johannes Rössel, thanks for that link. So it seems that I need to use a WeakReference in some form (as he says...) like the Java assertGC() call, but how can I write my own assertGC() if one does not already exist?

Comment: ... or a call like System.GC.HasReferences(WeakReference target) or System.GC.CanBeGarbageCollected(WeakReference target)

Comment: I never used all this and pretty much have no clue of that, but it appears to me that [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/08/11/10048629.aspx) more or less says "You can't find it out, actually" because in essence the question whether the GC wants to collect something is a different one from the question whether there are still references to an object. But don't take my word for granted; there are others who actually know about this ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this isn't possible at the moment with .NET 4. Though it is possible to know whether an object cannot be garbage collected (e.g. have a reference to it), there is no way to deterministically know whether an object can be garbage collected.

Using a WeakReference or a finaliser (and calling GC.Collect()) **may** collect the object, but unless it is in generation 0, there is a fair chance that it will not.

References:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/08/11/10048629.aspx (found by https://stackoverflow.com/users/73070/joey)
- http://www.abhisheksur.com/2010/07/garbage-collection-algorithm-with-use.html

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Running for 5 minutes solid, still no exception... Are you sure your code isn't referencing your object somewhere?

```
using System;

internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int cnt = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            ++cnt;
            bool gced = false;
            Action handler = () => gced = true;
            new Foo(handler);
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            Console.Out.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", cnt, gced);
            if (!gced)
            {
                throw new Exception("WTF?");
            }
        }
    }
}
class Foo
{
    private readonly Action _onFinalized;

    public Foo(Action finalized)
    {
        _onFinalized = finalized;
    }

    ~Foo()
    {
        if (_onFinalized != null) _onFinalized();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have modified my object to include your field, constructor and finalizer. When I run this test on my machine, the finalizer (and therefore the Action) does not always run. On my machine in a form with just one button to run the test, it works the first and second time this is run in a process, but does not run on the third time. On the fourth time, the object from the third time is finalized, but the new object is not! The unit test works on my machine but does not work on the build machine. GC.Collect() is not triggering the finalizer.

Comment: What about the waitforpendinfinalizer?

If you are in debug mode, the ref to `a` might be held by your debug vizualizers...

Comment: The code is all compiled with the debug flag, but the issue still occurs when a debugger is not attached to the application. Also - the issue is intermittent - it sometimes works.

Comment: Updated the code above, been running this for 10 minutes both in release and debug mode... 

Test procedure: choose build, then ctrl-f5

Comment: @Florian Doyon, thanks for keeping with it, I'll test this and get back to you.

Comment: Change the line 'new Foo(handler)' into:
'var foo = new Foo(handler);
for (var i = 0; i < 100000; i++ ) { new Foo(null); }'
... and it fails for me. You need to get the Foo object out of the first GC generation to make it fail.